# setting up composer installed in another project folder for a new project folder

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I wish to start a new symfony project,I want to use composer for the added advantages, but am having using the installed composer in my new project folder. The composer already installed came with Acquia dev desktop. when I run 'php composer.phar' in my new project folder I get this error "Could not open input file: composer.phar"

Comment: If you've got Composer already installed, just do `composer install`.

Comment: The error usually happens when one should have run `$ composer`  instead of  `$ php composer.phar`.

Answer (score 0):

Double check where your `composer.phar` file is located.

If it has been installed into your old project's folder, simply copy it to the new folder.

If it has been installed globally (i.e: it is not in your old project's folder), then make sure you are using the right command, you might need to simply do `composer install` instead of `php composer.phar`